# frontend-maven-plugin + grunt-contrib-watch - How to?

Tags: maven, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I can't figure out how to configure the **frontend-maven-plugin** in order to make the **grunt-contrib-watch** listen for file changes.

If I create a grunt execution like the following, Eclipse will stall at "Building workspace (95%)":

```
    <execution>
        <id>grunt-watch</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>grunt</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <arguments>watch</arguments>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

It won't finish until I kill the grunt process manually.

I've also tried to run *grunt watch* in a shell, and the task is been correctly executed, but I need to force a preject refresh in Eclipse, to make Maven copy the new resources into the build directory (target/classes).

What's the correct solution for my purpose?